# How to get non-expired urn when upload and translation model with autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm new to Autodesk Forge. I had created my own web application to upload and translate models and show them via viewer. But the urn I got expires in 24h. I mean, the objects expired in the created bucket. But the urn still can use to show in the viewer. how long will the urn expire? and how could I get the non-expired urn? Currently, I'm still using the trial. Is it after subscription, translation will return an urn that doesn't expire?

I tried searching but couldn't find the right answer. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the policy of your buckets to one of the following depending on how long you want to keep the URN valid. When creating buckets, it is required that applications set a retention policy for objects stored in the bucket. This cannot be changed at a later time. The retention policy on the bucket applies to all objects stored within. When creating a bucket, specifically set the policyKey to

- transient (24 hours) what you have right now
- temporary (30 days)
- persistent (permanent until you decide to delete the bucket)

Check this for more information - https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/developers_guide/retention-policy/

Comment: The answer was exactly what I needed. Thank you so much. Still has a small thing about the expired urn in the bucket. I noticed that the object has expired in the bucket, but if I store the urn data somewhere else I can still continue to use the urn in the viewer. So how long will this urn expire?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are interested in the duration of the generated bubbles.

Actually, After translation for a design model from your bucket, the generated object(svf|svf2) will not be impacted by the original design model in your bucket, that means, even the design model is expired or deleted, the generated object will be still there unless you explicated delete it by https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-manifest-DELETE, you can consider it as non-expired as long as you keep the original urn.